# Altium Online DRC not working

Tags: altium, drc

I always route with Online DRC on so that I can realise when I've done a mistake, although this suddenly stopped working during my last PCB design and its been very frustrating to have to perform a full design rule check for every slight change. If I move two components onto each other, or even place a via to short two tracks, Altium does not show any violation (the green 'x' marks) until I perform an actual Design Rule Check and then they show up, so I don't think its an issue of visibility. It also seems to be affecting other parts of the software as if I try to implement teardrops and I make sure to uncheck 'Force teardrops', I still get teardrops being placed and causing violations.

It seems that the issue is only present for my current PCB as it is working when I load up previous designs.

I have tried to turn it off, restart Altium, turn it back on, and restart Altium again but with no success. I have also tried to reset Altium's preferences but to no success either.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure Online DRC is enabled under Tools -> Preferences.
If that doesn't work, you can export your preferences from another project that has the desired behaviour to your current project (see buttons at the bottom of the Preferences dialog).

If that doesn't work, you may need to configure DRC (Tools -> Design Rules Check. There are check boxes for online and batch. You'll need to verify the various categories (Electrical, Routing, ...).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Somehow all of the boxes for online were unticked in the DRC and that seems to have been the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that the DRC errors are not turned off in the View Configuration panel (System Colors).

[image]